# How can I load a sound from the SD Card insted of the raw folder in my Android app useing Soundpool?

Tags: android, sd-card, soundpool

I am useing [this example](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html) to load and play sounds in my Androidapp. I am adding new sounds with `mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.sound1);`. How can I load a sound from the SD Card insted of the raw folder in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState()