# Playing Audio files from SD card

Tags: java, android, audio, soundpool

I wanted to load files from the SD card into a SoundPool as well as ringtones. I am able to successfully get the path of the files, and I am able to play them with MediaPlayer. However, I need the functionality of the SoundPool. I have tried SoundPool.load(String, int) but it appears to not load the file. Is it possible to load files from the SD card into a SoundPool, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293122/how-can-i-load-a-sound-from-the-sd-card-insted-of-the-raw-folder-in-my-android-a

Comment: I saw that when I was researching, but I don't understand how it's useful. I have access to the file's path, it's just not loading into the soundpool. Was there something I missed in that other question?

Comment: Try using this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11009250/847501

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the directory to your sdcard and append the file and extension, you can then use SoundPool with`load(String path, int priority)`, to access your file.

Or while not recommended you can even hardcode your path to "/sdcard/".

If the problem is not with getting the soundfile path then you can take a look at [Creating Sound Effects in Android](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html)