# can't play a sound file on android. having runtime errors

Tags: android, logcat

here's my code:

```
            String a = "R.raw."+b;//b  is a  user  input
            int toSpeak = Integer.parseInt(a);
            sound = MediaPlayer.create(trans.this, toSpeak);

            sound.start();
            sound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {                          
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sound.release();
                sound = null;
                }
            });
```

these  are my errors:

```
02-09 05:54:44.998: W/dalvikvm(1392): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a38b90)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392): Process: com.translator.ite, PID: 1392

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "R.raw.abandon"

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at com.translator.ite.trans$1.onClick(trans.java:60)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)

02-09 05:54:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1392):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check if the link works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528238/playing-audio-file-from-sdcard

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your error is in plain sight: you're trying to parse "R.raw.abandon" as an integer number in the second line from the top of the code you posted. Even a real android like Lt. Cdr. Data can't tell you which integer number "R.raw.abandon" is supposed to be ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to get id of resource using name:

```
int toSpeak = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/"+b, null, getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that kind of error. My final code that works ok for me :

```
final MediaPlayer mPlayer;
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.primeste_inactiv);
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
mPlayer.start();
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
  mPlayer.reset();
  mPlayer.release();
                    }
                });
```

My code has an extra line :

```
mPlayer.reset();
```