# Cant able to play an audio file from sdcard Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer;

String path = /storage/emulated/0/Audio/1429167704744.wav;
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), Uri.parse(path));
mPlayer.start();
```

Logs

```
04-20 13:04:09.667: E/AndroidRuntime(28202): Process: com.abs_ind.audio, PID: 28202 04-20 13:04:09.667: E/AndroidRuntime(28202): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference 
04-20 13:04:09.667: E/AndroidRuntime(28202):at com.bb_ind.test.Browse_Fragment.show_dialog(Browse_Fragment.java:71)
```

I'm getting `NullPointerException` when i start the Mediaplayer. I'm sure the file path is correct and the file is not corrupted. Thanks in advance .

Comment: probably the getActivity() i.e context is null. Please check the context.

Comment: duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528238/playing-audio-file-from-sdcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to specify the path directly, use the helper of `Environment` to get your file path. Declare the permissions in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then try the following code to play your audio file.

```
    final String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
            + File.separator + "1429167704744.wav";

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(path));
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this code:

`MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
 mp.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/yourdirectory/youraudiofile.wav");
 mp.prepare();
 mp.start();`

And did you added the following permission line in your manifest?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`